# Add new column based on sum of a column and grouped by 2 other columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Continent':['North America','North America','North America','Europe','Europe','Europe','Europe'],
                'Country': ['US','Canada','Mexico','France','Germany','Spain','Italy'],
                'Status': ['Member','Non-Member','Non-Member','Member','Non-Member','Member','Non-Member'],
                'Units': [27,5,4,10,15,8,8]})

print df

       Continent  Country      Status  Units
0  North America       US      Member     27
1  North America   Canada  Non-Member      5
2  North America   Mexico  Non-Member      4
3         Europe   France      Member     10
4         Europe  Germany  Non-Member     15
5         Europe    Spain      Member      8
6         Europe    Italy  Non-Member      8
```

I need to add 2 columns which are summary statistics about the Continents. I need a column with the sum of Units for Member countries and Non Member countries.

so that the final output would look like:

```
       Continent  Member Units  Non-Member Units  Country      Status  Units
0  North America            27                 9       US      Member     27
1  North America            27                 9   Canada  Non-Member      5
2  North America            27                 9   Mexico  Non-Member      4
3         Europe            18                23   France      Member     10
4         Europe            18                23  Germany  Non-Member     15
5         Europe            18                23    Spain      Member      8
6         Europe            18                23    Italy  Non-Member      8
```

It seems like I need to use groupby but I can't figure out how to take the groupby values and re-insert them into the dataframe as new columns.

```
summary_stats = df.groupby(['Continent','Status'])['Units'].sum()
print summary_stats

Continent      Status    
Europe         Member        18
               Non-Member    23
North America  Member        27
               Non-Member     9
Name: Units, dtype: int64
```

I also tried not using groupby with these:

```
df['Member Units'] = df['Units'][df['Status'] == 'Member'].sum()
df['Non-Member Units'] = df['Units'][df['Status'] == 'Non-Member'].sum()
```

but that doesn't differentiate by Continent so it just adds up all the Members and Non-Members

Any help is greatly appreicated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have `summary_stats` I think you can do something like:

```
df['Member Units'] = summary_stats[zip(df['Continent'].values, df['Status'].values)]
```

The reason you need to `zip` the Series values is that `df['Continent']` returns a series with indices, but you don't want that to happen.

Comment: I tried that but I get a long Pandas error ending with: "TypeError: "

Comment: I really don't understand why that doesn't work though - seems like the right way to select the value from a multi-index series

Comment: Oh, you're right! Sorry about that. I updated my answer to fix that. The reason is that `df['Continent']` returns the index together in the series, so it messes up the indices.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need first [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) for creating new `Series` `all_sum`. Then I think is better use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and if is member, get value from `Series`, if not, get `0`. Similar with non-members:

```
all_sum = df.groupby(['Continent','Status'])['Units'].transform(sum)
print all_sum
0    27
1     9
2     9
3    18
4    23
5    18
6    23
dtype: int64

df['Member Units'] = np.where(df['Status'] == 'Member', all_sum, 0)
df['Non-Member Units'] = np.where(df['Status'] != 'Member', all_sum, 0)
print df
       Continent  Country      Status  Units  Member Units  Non-Member Units
0  North America       US      Member     27            27                 0
1  North America   Canada  Non-Member      5             0                 9
2  North America   Mexico  Non-Member      4             0                 9
3         Europe   France      Member     10            18                 0
4         Europe  Germany  Non-Member     15             0                23
5         Europe    Spain      Member      8            18                 0
6         Europe    Italy  Non-Member      8             0                23
```

Comment: Please check my solution with `0` if I it is correct. If not, I can change it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `summary_stats`, you can use `merge()` after reshape it:

```
summary = summary_stats.reset_index().pivot(index='Continent', columns='Status', values='Units')

summary['Continent'] = summary.index

df = df.merge(summary, on='Continent')
```

Then just rename columns as you want